# Resources for overclocking-friendly hardware

Tags: performance, computer-building, overclocking, 3d-modeling

Is there a website that maintains a list of hardware that can be overclocked easily with good performance and reliability? I mostly want this for using with graphics-intensive programs such as AutoCAD and 3DSMax, but better gaming performance would always be a plus.

Just to be clear, this is for a 'power user', not a gamer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[TomsHardware](http://www.tomshardware.com) is a pretty good resource for this kind of thing. The reviews and tests are usually pretty thorough.

Answer (score 1):

[**www.overclockers.com**](http://www.overclockers.com/)

Comment: This is THE resource. Use Google's site:www.overclockers.com parameter to find information about your particular hardware and software. You'll need to d/l Prime95 for overnight tests of stability. You will also need to invest in higher quality memory, motherboards, and a power supply to overlock with stability.

Right now Intel's 45nM Core 2 chips are proving very overlockable.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a big fan of [HardOCP](http://www.hardocp.com/). I don't know another site that stress-tests, say, [power supplies](http://www.hardocp.com/article/2009/07/28/bfg_ex1000_1000_watt_power_supply/) so thoroughly.